# Would you recommend JavaScript for GNOME desktop apps?

Tags: javascript, gnome, seed

With the arrival of the new [GNOME Developer Center](http://developer.gnome.org/) I stumbled across JavaScript bindings for the gobject libraries. Now I would love to read a comment from an expert if he (or she) would recommend / consider using those for a desktop application. That involves consideration of aspects like

- API simplicity and usability
- developer documentation
- stability
- scalability
- [gjs](http://live.gnome.org/Gjs/) or [Seed](http://live.gnome.org/Seed)?

At once: Are those APIs ready for usage or would it be better to wait a little until it is more established? Can you develop a whole application in JS or would you restrict usage to  scripting purposes?

Comment: I believe the majority of gnome-shell ui (the new window manager for gnome3) is written in javascript. Check out https://github.com/philn/gnome-shell-extensions for some examples. But from what I can see it's just a way of hooking functionality into the window manager, not a full app.

Comment: If your project is open source, I believe using JavaScript has one major advantage: more developer contribution. A project written in JS will have a much larger developer audience that is willing to contribute. Most in technology know JavaScript at some level. I personally haven't contributed much to open source desktop software even though I'd like to, mainly because I don't have much C/C++ or Python knowledge. Further, people who know C/C++ and are willing to contribute to OSS are mostly already involved in something; those assets are stretched thin. JS knowledge isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Through GObject Instrospection you have access to the same API provided by the libraries written in C (with the lingo for JavaScript).

The documentation needs to be improved.  However, you can always use C documentation as fallback. Nevertheless, you can help with the documentation for JavaScript as you learn ;-)

gnome-shell is written in JavaScript and C, therefore JavaScript is a first class citizen in GNOME 3.  It should not have performance penalties (if so, it should be improved).

There is a discussion about the future of JavaScript in GNOME (whether to use gjs or seed), you can read the thread here: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2011-April/msg00147.html

As I said previously, with GObject instrospection you can write a whole application in JavaScript. For instance, you can take a look to "The Board", a new application written in JavaScript https://live.gnome.org/TheBoardProject

Comment: Actually gnome-shell is not written just in javascript, it is written in C, as well as javascript. I do agree you can write a application solely in javascript, or more accurately gjs or seed, making full use of introspection to access things like Gtk, Clutter, Rest, etc. I also agree about the documentation

Comment: @JamesHurford Indeed, gnome-shell is written in both, C and Javascript.  I fixed it. Thanks!